# Expected Identifier - non-ES6 version of script giving error in IE11

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I'm trying to work out why a script is giving me errors in IE 11. I've trimmed it down to just:

```
/*
 * enter-view.js is library
 */

(function (factory) {
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    define(factory);
  } else if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) {
    module.exports = factory();
  } else {
    window.enterView = factory.call(this);
  }
})(function () {
  const lib = function ({
    selector,
    enter = function () {},
    exit = function () {},
    progress = function () {},
    offset = 0,
    once = false
  }) {
     // other code here - but trimmed down
  };

  return lib;
});
```

The error code says line 14, column 25 - which is:

```
  const lib = function ({
```

I can't work out why its giving me that error though. Any suggestions?

BTW the outputted code is from Babel, with this config:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-template-literals",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-arrow-functions",
    "babel-polyfill"
   ]
}
```

Comment: `const` is ES6, as is argument destructuring and default properties

Comment: @CertainPerformance - so should it be a `var` instead? This one is created using Babel (with backwards compatibility, so it should in be making the code work on older versions). The original line in the ES6 version is: `const lib = ({`

Comment: If that was created with Babel, your configuration is incorrect, because the code it's outputting is *definitely not* ES5 compatible

Comment: @CertainPerformance thanks. I've included my Babel config. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: try adding `@babel/plugin-transform-destructuring` ... since the documentation for that plugin points to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment which includes the syntax you are using [Setting_a_function_parameters_default_value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Setting_a_function_parameters_default_value)

Comment: @Bravo thanks - I tried to install it but its moaning: `UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @babel/core@^7.0.0-0`. Looks like I need to see if I can get babel updated on the server

Comment: I don't babel, and just send anyone using IE browser to [a page compatible with their browser](http://info.cern.ch/hypertext/WWW/TheProject.html) :D

Comment: As a work around I run the plugin through babeljs.io's website, and then used the compiled code. Seems ok now. Need to really do a full rebuild of the server though, as I can't for the life of me get Babel to update to v7 (which seems to be needed for that babel-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

It seems in this line `const lib = function ({selector,` you are trying to use [destructuring_assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) which is not supported in IE. Try to use babel compiler

Comment: Thanks, I'm actually alreadyusing babel. {
`  "plugins": [
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-template-literals",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-arrow-functions",
    "babel-polyfill"
   ]
}` ... what else should I add into the config so it takes care of that?

Comment: not only destructring, also *default values* ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Setting_a_function_parameters_default_value